# How to use a variable to select a column that has a number as a name

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the variable `f_year` instead of `2004`. How can I do it?

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

f_year <- "2004"

df <- tibble(`2004` = c(1,2),
             `2005` = c(1,4),
             `2006` = c(2,7))
df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   `2004` `2005` `2006`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      1      1      2
#> 2      2      4      7

df2 <- df %>% mutate(`2004` = ifelse(`2004` == 1, 4, `2004`))
df2
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   `2004` `2005` `2006`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      4      1      2
#> 2      2      4      7
Created on 2023-10-23 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

As Limey said in the comment, `mutate_at` has been superseded, so we can use `across` with `mutate` instead

```
> df %>%
+     mutate(across(all_of(f_year), ~ if_else(.x == 1, 4, .x)))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  `2004` `2005` `2006`
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      4      1      2
2      2      4      7
```

---

I guess you can use `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(f_year, ~ ifelse(. == 1, 4, .))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  `2004` `2005` `2006`
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      4      1      2
2      2      4      7
```

Comment: `mutate_at` has been superseded.

Comment: @Limey thanks for the feedback, just aware of that fact :P

Comment: I believe this approach will throw a warning regarding "use of external vectors in dplyr". The clean approach would be `mutate(across(all_of(f_year), ~ ....`, the ideal method for using character vectors of variable names in tidyselect . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @GuedesBF I didn't get any warning....

Comment: Hum that is weird. I doubled checked it a minute ago, and got this warning from the "updated" answer:

Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `across(f_year, ~if_else(.x == 1, 4, .x))`.
Caused by warning:
! Using an external vector in selections was deprecated in tidyselect 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `all_of()` or `any_of()` instead.
  # Was:
  data %>% select(f_year)

  # Now:
  data %>% select(all_of(f_year))

See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.

Comment: I am using dplyr 1.1.2, with R 4.3.1

Comment: @GuedesBF I used `dplyr` 1.1.3 with R 4.3.1

Comment: I do not see any mention to dropping the warning message in the 1.1.3 changelog, that is surprising. Will check that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255711/discussion-between-guedesbf-and-thomasiscoding).

Comment: @GuedesBF I think you are right, there was a warning but it was weird that not appearing right away. but I can see it now when re-run. I updated the solution as you suggested. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: Oh, nice to know I was not lost in package versions. I would recommend including `all_of`, then, it may be a little safer then directly feeding strings to `select` or `mutate`. An example of trouble from the original approach would be this: What to expect when we use `Sepal.Length <- "Species"; mutate(iris, Sepal.Length, \(z)...)`, should mutate be over the "Species" string or `Sepal.Length` column?

Comment: May be a little farfetched in the example...

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a one liner (base R):

```
df[df[,f_year] == 1, f_year] <- 4 # More data.frame-like
```

or

```
df[[f_year]][df[[f_year]] == 1] <- 4 # More list/vecor-like
```

Answer (score 4):

Two other options:

```
df %>% mutate( {{ f_year }} := ifelse( get(f_year) == 1, 4, get(f_year) ))
```

[The `:=` is not a typo.]

```
df %>% mutate(across(f_year, \(x) ifelse(x == 1, 4, x)))
```

[Essentially the same as ThomasIsCoding's revised suggestion.  They were first.]